# Access setting listbox rowsource with vba at opening form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to populate a listbox with the data from a select query in a form using vba, for that I tried on open and on charge events on the form:

```
me.listbox.rowsourcetype = "Table/Query"
me.listbox.rowsource = "Clients"
me.requery
```

But it does not populate the listbox neither with the same code in the onOpen and in the onCharge events

Can you tell me how to solve my problem please?

Comment: Please copy and paste code from VBE! Lowercase chars shows it's not copied from there (recognized keywords like Me will be PascalCase then)! `Form_Open` is correct event for setting the listbox rowsource. Add a [breakpoint](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/6252/adding-a-breakpoint-to-your-code) to one line of your code to verify it's executed. `Me.Requery`doesn't make sense at that time as no data loaded to form!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve the problem.

I cannot make it work using my query name but it works if you write the SQL select

Me.listbox.resource = "Select * from etc......"

Thank you.

Comment: `Clients`is a query name? Bad naming, everyone assumes this being a table, but doesn't matter. Listbox.Rowsource can be query name only too, so there is no query or table named Clients! Fornat your answer (code-blocks)!!